# Duplicate Project Path Issue in PhpStorm

Tags: php, url, path, phpstorm

When running a PHP project in PhpStorm, I encounter a 404 error due to the URL containing a duplicated project path. This is my PHP project structure
[image]

This is the URL I encounter during runtime:
[image]
I would like to understand why "start" duplication occurs and how to resolve the issue. I tried modifying the run configuration in PhpStorm, but each modification only affects a single file. Additionally, when I created a new project, the issue didn't occur.

Comment: The first `start` is the project name, as in `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/`. The rest -- is the path in the actual project.

Comment: if it only meant to be once (I mean: everything is fine just that `start` is duplicated for some unknown reason) ... then it must be something wrong with this project config (hard to say what it might be unless you know all the aspects of your project set up/how you did it)...

Comment: What I can suggest here: 1) close the IDE; 2) Go to the project folder, then backup and delete the `.idea` subfolder (that's where project config/settings are stored); 3) Launch the IDE again and open this project (if it's not there -- just use "Open" and point to the project root folder) -- it will make a fresh one from those files.